# How to get search content from different locations?

Tags: google-search

On a desktop computer, whenever we use Google search, we get results of nearby locations only.

- Is it possible to get more search results of other locations?
- If yes, what I need to do in my desktop computer?

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll to the bottom of any Google search page, you'll see your location.

To search from another location you can use the following URL: http://isearchfrom.com/

In that page, you can specify the country, language, city and other location parameters.
Then, enter your search text and hit the search button. A new page will be opened in Google with your desired location parameters.

Answer (score -1):

You can increase the number of non-local results following these steps:

- Eliminate all browser add-on toolbars -- most are advertising gimmicks to redirect your search.
- Delete all cookies, either using the browser or third-party tool such as [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download).
- Forbid use of location data by applications. This is OS dependent, for example, as in [Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/221869/how-to-disable-or-configure-location-tracking-in-windows-10/) or [Mac OS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204690).
- Use a search service that does not track you, e.g. [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/).